# Druid appending "StructuredData{value=" with LATEST Aggregation on JSON type column object

Tags: druid, druid-rs, druid-extensions, apache-druid

Following is the Druid sql query and I am trying to apply LATEST aggregation function on Json type customMetadata object

```
Select sid, 
LATEST(JSON_QUERY("customMetadata", '$'), 1000) as "test" 
from xyz 
where 1=1 
group by sid
limit 1
```

**output**:
sid = 1

test = StructuredData{value={supportedAbi=armeabi-v7a}}

**Expected output**

sid = 1

test = {"supportedAbi":"armeabi-v7a"}

Following is second query where I am just trying to read specific param under that JSON object and applying LATEST over it. That scenario is working fine and none of the additional string getting added there

```
Select sid, 
LATEST(JSON_VALUE("customMetadata", '$.supportedAbi'), 1000.000000) as "test" 
from xyz 
where 1=1 
group by sid
limit 1
```

**Output**

sid=1

test = armeabi-v7a

I wanted to know why Druid is appending "StructuredData{value=" in first scenario, Any suggestion on how can we avoid that?